# Integrable in subinterval

Tags: calculus

can someone please help me with proving the following: 
 If $f$ is Integrable (Riemann) in the closed interval $[x,y]$, then it is also integrable in any closed subinterval $[a,b]$ of $[x,y]$. I found the following proof online, but I think this is wrong: 
 Take $\epsilon>0$. There exists a partition $P$ such  that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$. 
 Look at the partition $P_1 = \{a,b\} \cup (P\cap[a,b])$. It satisfies $U(f|_{[a,b]},P_1)<U(f,P)$ and also $L(f|_{[a,b]},P_1)>L(f,P)$, so we get $U(f|_{[a,b]},P_1)-L(f|_{[a,b]},P_1)<\epsilon$. 
 I really don't see why $L(f|_{[a,b]},P_1)>L(f,P)$ and why $U(f|_{[a,b]},P_1)<U(f,P)$. I think I even have a counter example. I know that $P_1 \subset P$ so it looks true, but $P_1$ is not a partition of $[x,y]$ and $P$ is not a partition of $[a,b]$. Can someone give me a vaild proof, or explain why the above is correct?

Comment: The difference of two Riemann sums in the subinterval must be smaller than of in the bigger interval.